# PHP: PSR-15 Outbound Middlewares, modifiying the response through middlewares?

Tags: php, middleware

For a new project I would like to use middlewares to work with **incoming** requests and then subsequent with **outgoing** responses.

I am some what confused and lost on how to achieve this, while adhering to PSR-15.
Every depiction I found shows the application as "[onion](https://www.google.com/search?q=psr-15%20middleware&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjixLylqtvpAhUkgM4BHUJlA1AQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=psr-15%20middleware&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQGDoGCAAQBxAeOggIABAHEAUQHjoICAAQCBAHEB5Qg64JWI-0CWDGvAloAHAAeACAAVuIAYYEkgEBNpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img&ei=7y7SXqKRI6SAur4PwsqNgAU&client=firefox-b-d#imgrc=Gr5QVn2D303pJM)" where the middlewares act as layers through which the request **and response** passes. ([Double Pass](https://mwop.net/blog/2018-01-23-psr-15.html))

> request --> middlewares --> handler --> middlewares --> response

But the current valid [PSR-15 MiddlewareInterface](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-15/#22-psrhttpservermiddlewareinterface) requires a RequestInterface and returns a ResponseInterface. So for me it seems that the "onion" is cut in half:

> request --> middlewares --> handler --> response

**The question is:**
How can I push and modify a *response* through a (middleware?) stack if the MiddlewareInterface requires a *request*?

I hacked together a quick and [dead-simple test project](https://github.com/Ironcheese/Mini-Framework) to show what I am trying to achieve.
Here is the "heart" of the app:

```php
// bootstrap/app.php

$request = Factory::createRequest();

// Simple Routes... just for the test
$router = new Router([
    '/' => [CampaignController::class, 'show'],
    // .... route definitions ...
]);

// Match the incoming request to a handler
$handler = $router->match($request);

// Inbound Middlewares, these are PSR-15 conform
$inbound_middlewares = [
    new Alpha, // e.g. Check CSRF etc...
    new Bravo,
    new Charlie,
];

// Dispatch the request to a handler through the inbound middleware stack
$handler_response = Stack::pipe($request)->to($handler)->through($inbound_middlewares);

// Outbound Middlewares, these are NOT PSR-15 conform...
$outbound_middlewares = [
    new Delta, // e.g. minify HTML etc...
    new Foxtrot,
    new Golf,
];
// Pipe the Handler Response through the outbound middleware Stack
$server_response = Stack::pipe($handler_response)->through($outbound_middlewares);

// Emit the generated response back to the client
$emitter = Factory::createResponseEmitter();
$emitter->emit($server_response);
```

I looked at the code of Laravel and other solutions but could not find how they work or modify the response.

Maybe I am total off in my thinking or I just haven't fully grasped the concept...
Usually I am working with Laravel, so these "lower" level concepts are new to me.

Edit: 
Clarification: My test app works, but I wonder if its the "right" approach.

Answer (score 1):

The interface allows both mutation of the `Request` and `Response` in each middleware and creation of new responses.

Psedo-code:

```php
class TrimUrlMiddleware implements middleware {
  function process($request, $handler) {
    $path = $request->getRequestTarget();
    $request = $request->withRequestTarget(substr($path, 0, 100));
    // Passes it to next layer and returns response
    return $handler->handle($request);
  }
}

class AddResponseHeader implements middleware {
  function process($request, $handler) {
    // Passes it to next layer and returns response;
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    $response = $response->withHeader("X-Custom", "SomeValue");
    return $response;
  }
}

class FlakyMiddleware implements middleware {
  function process($request, $handler) {
    if (rand(0,100) == 0) {
       return new Response(500, "Random failure");
    }

    // Passes it to next layer and returns response
    return $handler->handle($request);
  }
}
```